Missing longintrepr.h in Python3.12 when setting up Charm-Crypto on Ubuntu
I have been trying to set up Charm-Crypto from https://github.com/JHUISI/charm on Ubuntu 24 LTS.
I have installed the required dependencies:

GMP 5.x
PBC
OPENSSL

I have tried installing the Python3.12 headers with sudo apt install python3-dev but on running
sudo apt make install I get:
...
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing Charm_Crypto.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to Charm_Crypto.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to Charm_Crypto.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to Charm_Crypto.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'Charm_Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'README'
adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
writing manifest file 'Charm_Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying charm/config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/charm
running build_ext
building 'charm.core.math.pairing' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python3.12 -c charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.o
In file included from charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c:30:
charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.h:39:10: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
   39 | #include <longintrepr.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
make: *** [Makefile:43: install] Error 1

How may I resolve the issue with the missing longintrepr?
I have already tried installing the python3.12 headers using sudo apt install python-dev and I thought this would fix the issue but it did not.
